# Will my Steam play be available on Linux?

Tags: games, steam

So right now I have Steam on Windows 8.1. I already looked it up and apparently Steam actually is available for Ubuntu. I am planning on dual booting Ubuntu but to make things easier I will just put Steam on Ubuntu. Will all the stuff I have saved like my history and games and history on the games be saved? I know I have an account for Steam but I'm not sure if it saves all this.

Answer (score 1):

Although Steam is available and officially supported for Ubuntu, not all of the games sold there are. Visit the store page of the games you want to keep playing and look out for the system requirements:

[image]

If it has a Linux tab, then you should be fine. Else, your game will most likely not run on Ubuntu, at the most with Wine, but don't have too high expectations.

If the game is Linux compatible, your game progress etc. will still be available, as Steam stores that on its servers.

Only with screenshots you have to watch out. After you quit a Steam game and you took screenshots, you are prompted to upload them. If you don't, they'll only stay locally.

Answer (score 0):

Steam uses cloud to save your game data so it doesn't matter which OS you use, the necessary thing is that you are logged in as your steam user.

Comment: Okay. Thank you all. Also, a little bit unrelated, but I tried installing Steam on Ubuntu and it wouldn't work. Apparently the solution is to delete some type of 'appcache' folder. Where is this located if I downloaded 'Steam-launcher' from the Ubuntu software Center?

Comment: I also had problems with that. Try to uninstall Steam and then go to the official website and download the .deb file. Then run it and it should work fine.